# Proof about convergence of an arbitrary subsequence

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, proof-explanation

My calculus notes contain the following theorem and its proof:

> If the sequence $(x_n)$ converges to $a$ and if $(x_{n_k})$ is any subsequence of $(x_n)$, then $x_{n_k}\to a$ when $k\to \infty$

Proof:

> Let $\varepsilon>0$. Choose $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n\geq N$ implies $|x_n-a|<\varepsilon$.

> Since $n_k\in\mathbb{N}$ and $n_1<n_2<...,$ it's clear that $n_k\geq k$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$.

> Then, $k\geq N$ implies $n_k\geq N$. Thus, $|x_{n_k}-a|<\varepsilon$. In other words, $x_{n_k}\to a$ when $k\to\infty$.

I don't under why we can affirm that $n_k\geq k$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you written "$k = 1\ 2\ 3\ 4\ 5\ 6\ \dots$" and then below it a valid sequence of $n_k$s?  You'll see what is going on very quickly.  (In fact, you'll see what you're missing.)

Comment: You want $x_{n_k} \to a$ when $k\to \infty.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true because the sequence $(n_k)$ is strictly increasing. Therefore for each $k$

> $\{n_1,\ldots,n_k\} \subset \{1,\ldots,n_k \}$.

The set on the LHS has $k$ elements, the set on the RHS $n_k$ elements. Set inclusion implies $k \le n_k$.